# Thread pool, Threadsafe Queue, OOP

Tags: multithreading, delphi, queue, threadpool, indy

Lets say there are some non-PC devices on an ethernet network and based on the given API, i can communicate with them using UDP.

I would like to use a thread pool and a thread safe queue for the UDP communication. Every worker thread would have its own indy TIdUDPclient instance. The communication is like sending one UDP datagram to a device then waiting for the answer. The answer is a UDP datagram with >2 bytes at the data segment.

The device is represented by the *TDevice* class instances.

```
TDevice = class(TObject)
private
  ...
  FStatus: byte;
  ...
public
  ...
  function GetStatus(): integer; //API commandID = 68 (Getting device Status)
end;
```

*thPool* is for creating/managing the threads and pushing the job to the queue:

```
TthPool = class(TObject)
private
  FQueue: TThreadedQueue<TrUDPdirectJob*>;
  FthWorkers: TList<TthWorker>;
public
  constructor Create( AthCount, AQueueDepth: integer); //creating the pool here
  function SendCommand( ArSendJob: TrSendJob );
end;

function SendCommand(ArSendJob TrSendJob): integer; 
begin
  ...
  FQueue.PushItem( ArSendJob );
end;
```

One function of *TDevice* is for getting the status of the hardware it represents and set the value of it's *FStatus* based on the received answer:

```
function TDevice.GetStatus(): integer;  //command byte: 68
const
  PARAMSLENGTH = 4;
var
  rSendJob: TrSendJob*        
begin
  rSendJob.IP := self.FIP;
  rSendJob.port := self.Fport;
  rSendJob.commandID := 68;
  rSendJob.paramslength := PARAMLENGTH ; //need to send the length (API req) 
  SetLength( rSendJob.params, PARAMSLENGTH  );  
  rSendJob.params[0] := $A; //just some parameters along the commandID
  rSendJob.params[1] := $B;
  rSendJob.params[2] := $C;
  rSendJob.params[3] := $D;
  ...
  thPool.SendCommand( rSendJob );   //pushing the job to the queue   
end;

*TrSendJob = record  //Job define
  ip: string;
  port: integer;
  commandID: byte;        
  params: Tparams; //Array of byte
  paramslength: byte;
end;
```

Sending out the UDP datagram from the worker thread:

```
procedure TthWorker.Execute;
var
  sendBuffer: TIDbytes;
  rBuffer: TIdBytes;
  rSendJob: TrSendJob;
begin
  inherited;
  repeat
    FQueue.PopItem(rSendJob); //Getting the job from the queue
    //Building the sending buffer
    sendBuffer[0] := rSendJob. ... ; 
    ...
    FIdUDPclient.SendBuffer( rSendJob.IP, rSendJob.port, sendBuffer );
    if FIdUDPclient.receiveBuffer(rbuffer, RECTIMEOUT_GLOBAL) >= 1 then
    begin
      //
    end;
  until Terminated;
end;
```

In sum, *thPool*'s *SendCommand* is pushing the jobs into the queue, the worker thread pulling the Job from the queue and sending out the UDP datagram, then its getting back the answer bytes in *rbuffer*. But at this point, how to send the contents of receivebuffer back to *TDevice* instance for processing? What is the proper (OOP) way of doing this? I need to do the processing inside a *TDevice* method.

Is that a proper solution, if i define a plus method pointer field at *TrSendJob* so the worker thread knows what method to call for processing the buffer and set *FState* value of *TDevice*?

```
TProcessReceiveBuffer = function(ArBuffer: TIdBytes): integer;

TrSendJob = record  //Job define
  ip: string;
  port: integer;
  commandID: byte;        
  params: Tparams; //Tparams array of byte
  paramslength: byte;
  *ProcessReceiveBuffer: TProcessReceiveBuffer; //pointer to a TDevice method thats processing the receivebuffer
end;
```

Or, the whole concept is wrong.

Comment: What is the purpose of threading here?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there could be lots of device, some polling threads and the user activity through the VCL, but mostly for learning! (:

Comment: It sounds to me as though threading will make matters worse. Massive increase in complexity, and probably poorer performance.

Comment: But at least for not locking the UI, i need some threading.

Comment: If you want to use synchronous IO then yes. But you can just have a single IO thread for that.

Comment: But lets say i have 40 device. Won't be it faster to get the states from all of them using five threads instead of one?

Comment: Why would it be faster? Are you expecting this to be CPU bound?

Comment: True, i have only one ethernet interface anyway. (:

Comment: But cannot i send other datagrams while waiting for other's answer?

Comment: Well, that's true. But now you are getting to the heart of it. I think a lot of people think that any program can be made faster by throwing threads at it. And it's very often not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But at this point, how to send the contents of receivebuffer back to TDevice instance for processing?

You could include a `TDevice` object pointer in `TrSendJob`, then `TthWorker` will know which `TDevice` to pass the buffer to.

Or, you could put a buffer and `TEvent` into `TrSendJob`, then have `TthWorker` fill the buffer and signal the event, then have `TDevice.GetStatus()` wait for the event signal and process the buffer.

Comment: Thank you. Should i use a separate IdUDPClient instance for all the worker threads?

Comment: Yes, since you are wanting to send multiple datagrams in parallel. Give each thread its own client, and then have the current job use its executing thread's client as needed.